# Reading / Writing a specific pin From i2c in shell_exec

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c, shell-exec

Is there a way to write to a pin on the mcp23017 chip in Shell / bash without having to change/ update the other pins

This is what I found

```
sudo i2cset -y 1 0x20 0x14 0x01 # Sets bus 0x20 port A to 00000001
```

In python i can specify a pin :

```
bus_0 = IOPi(0x20) # Choose Chip
bus_0.set_port_direction(0, 0x00) #Set port A/0 to Output(For all pins)
bus_0.write_port(0, 0xFF) # Can write all pins 
bus_0.write_pin(1, 1) # can write specific pin
```

Is the only option to write a script that takes the input from shell_exec and does the job?